# Передача двумерного динамического массива в функцию (Си)

Tags: c

Подскажите как правильно передать двумерный динамический массив в функцию. Функция не возвращает значения (void), массив в ней должен изменяться. При передачи в аргумент просто int **Arr, создается копия и изменяется только копия, мне же нужно чтобы изменялся именно передаваемый через аргументы массив.

```
 void ArrayInput2(int **X, int n, int m, int **Y, int a, int b)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
    int i, j;
    X = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
      X[i] = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
      for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
      {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &X[i][j]);
      }
    }

    Y = (int**)malloc(a * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i<a; i++)
    {
      Y[i] = (int*)malloc(b * sizeof(int));
      for (j = 0; j<b; j++)
      {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &Y[i][j]);
      }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: "При передачи в аргумент просто int **Arr, создается копия" - это сомнительно.

Comment: Функция заполнения массива из файла. Сама функция работает корректно, если попытаться вывести на экран считанный с файла массив сразу в функции, все выводится, но при попытке затем вывести этот же массив уже из функции main программа падает...

Comment: Пусть Ваша функция возвращает `int **`.

Comment: @Uefa Покажите код.

Comment: Не получиться, т.к. из файла нужно считать 2 массива. Простейший способ, это объявить функцию void и передать через аргументы обе функции и за 1 вызов функции все записать. Иначе при каждом вызове функции программа записывает в массив данные сначала файла.

Comment: "создается копия и изменяется только копия" - копия *чего*? В С нет никаких встроенных средств создания копий массивов (кроме обертки в структуру), поэтому никакой "копии массива" передаваться не может в принципе. Вы что-то выдумываете.

Comment: @AnT думаю, уже всем ясно - автор передает в функцию `int**` и там распределяет память

Comment: @Igor: Что такое `int **&`?

Comment: @Igor: В что же время в вопросе автор утверждает, что массив передается в функцию *извне*.

Comment: @Igor: Вопрос помечен тегом [C], поэтому куда и зачем вы тут собрались ставить `&` мне не ясно.

Comment: @AnT, я передаю в функцию int**, в функции выделяю память и заполняю массив, функция не возвращает значения (void), при попытке далее работать с этим массивом из функции main программа падает.

Comment: Передавайте `int ***X` (и `int *** Y`) и обращайтесь внутри к `*X` (`*Y`). Т.е. при вызове передавайте `&X` (адрес вашего указателя на массив, который будете создавать в функции)

Comment: @Uefa: Так а *почему* функция возвращает `void`? Это - жесткое требование?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, "возвращаемые" параметры вам в такой ситуации придется передавать "по указателю". Так как сами "возвращаемые" параметры имеют тип `int **`, то при передаче "по указателю" они превратятся в `int ***`

Во-вторых, чтобы не путаться в "звездочках", выделение памяти я бы порекомендовал делать через следующую идиому

```
dst = malloc(N * sizeof *dst);
```

(и заодно избавиться от манеры явно приводить результат `malloc`)

```
void ArrayInput2(int ***pX, int n, int m, int ***pY, int a, int b)
{
  ...
  *pX = malloc(n * sizeof **pX);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    (*pX)[i] = malloc(m * sizeof *(*pX)[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
      fscanf(file, "%d", &(*pX)[i][j]);
  }
  ...
```

В-третьих, в качестве опциональной модификации можно предложить выделять память второго уровня единым блоком, а не множественными вызовами `malloc`

```
void ArrayInput2(int ***pX, int n, int m, int ***pY, int a, int b)
{
  ...
  *pX = malloc(n * sizeof **pX);
  **pX = malloc(n * m * sizeof ***pX);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    (*pX)[i] = **pX + i * m;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
      fscanf(file, "%d", &(*pX)[i][j]);
  }
  ...
```

При вызове такой функции, разумеется, надо не забывать передавать именно указатели на указатели-приемники

```
int **X, **Y;
ArrayInput2(&X, 10, 20, &Y, 30, 40);
```

---

Но, вообще говоря, код надо было бы переделать по другому. Функции, которая читает две матрицы быть не должно. Должна быть функция, которая читает только *одну* матрицу из данного файла из возвращает ее через возвращаемое значение

```
int **matrix_input(FILE *f, int n, int m)
```

Тогда и "звездочек" этих многоэтажных было бы меньше.

Comment: `избавиться от манеры явно приводить результат malloc`, если не секрет, почему? Чем не угодил такой каст?

Comment: @NewView: Он много чем не угодил. Во-первых, он нинафиг не нужен. Делать что-то ненужное, а затем спрашивать "чем не угодил" - странное занятие, особенно если речь идет о чем-то настолько костыльно-некрасивом, как касты. Кастов в коде быть не должно вообще, за редким исключением тех случаев, когда они неизбежны.

Comment: Во-вторых, такое приведение забивает код упоминаниями имен типов. Имена типов должны упоминаться только в объявлениях. Сам код же (statements) должен быть настолько типонезависим, насколько это возможно. Упоминаний имен конкретных типов там быть не должно (опять же: за редким исключением тех случаев, когда они неизбежны). Это пресловутый принцип DRY (don't repeat yourself): не надо повторять то, что и так уже известно.

Comment: В Си достаточно двух звёзд, зачем три?!

Comment: И умножение для подсчёта необходимого размера памяти теоретически может вызвать переполнение целого.

Comment: @0andriy: О каком "достатночно двух звезд" вы ведете речь? Если вам нужно вернуть через параметр значение типа `int **`, то параметр придется объявлять как `int ***`.

Comment: @AnT, DRY + солидарен

Comment: Просто не нужно так делать. Вы сами это в конце ответа написали, чем и подтвердили моё утверждение.

Answer (score 2):

А не проще создать структуру, а не городить эти трех этажные звезды

```
typedef struct matrix_s
{
    int *data;
    size_t width;
    size_t height;
} matrix_s;
```

и функцию для создания

```
matrix_s *matrix_new(size_t w, size_t h);
```

и передавать ее в вашу функцию загрузки из файла, что-то типа

```
int load_matrix_fromfile(matrix_s *a, matrix_s *b, const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
        return -1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a->width * a->height; i++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &a->data[i]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < b->width * b->height; i++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &b->data[i]);
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

а для чтения записи матрицы использовать

```
int *matrix_setget(matrix_s *m, size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return m->data + m->width * y + x;
}
matrix_s *m = matrix_new(3, 3);
*matrix_setget(m, 0, 0) = 15;
```

Мне кажется читать код будет точно приятнее и понятней

Comment: Может стоит пояснить в тексте ответа, что вы в т.ч. предлагаете использовать "настоящую" матрицу, а не массив указателей на строки (как в коде вопроса)

Comment: Ну, я думаю это и так понятно.

Comment: Мне понятно, ТС и таким же новичкам, зашедшим из гугла -- не уверен

Comment: @avp: А чем это "настоящее" чем исходный вариант? Во-первых, оба варианта являются равноценными способами реализации двумерного массива (матрицы). У каждого из них свои достоинства и недостатки и, соответственно, области применения. Во-вторых, разница между этими двумя вариантами не так уж и велика, если обратить внимание на то, что память второго уровня запросто может быть выделена единым блоком (как в моем ответе).

Comment: @AnT, тем, что память выделяется так же, как и для  матрицы `int a[N][M];` и отсутствует вектор указателей на строки (даже если выделить память под все элементы одним блоком (кстати, а зачем в таком случае нужен вектор указателей? Это не будет провоцировать ошибки?)).  По поводу достоинств метода с вектором указателей -- imho только 1) естественная для программиста индексация элементов (без дополнительных усилий) 2) теоретическая возможность работать в экстремальных условиях фрагментации памяти