# как передать в функцию динамический двумерный массив?

Tags: c

Есть двумерный динамический массив, который надо передать в функцию через указатели. При первой же попытке достать элемент из памяти элемент появляется ошибка доступа. Если делать так, как описано тут [Передача двумерного динамического массива в функцию (Си)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840700/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%A1%D0%B8), то тоже все бесполезно. Вот та самая злосчастная функция.

```
void EDITTEXT(char **a, int y, char *b, int dsize) {
int i, x, d = 0, k;

for (i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
    for (x = 0; a[i][x] != 0; x++) {
        for (k = 0; k < dsize; k++) {
            if (a[i][x] == b[k]) d++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", d);
}
```

а - двумерный динамический массив, 
b - динамический массив.

Надо найти количество одинаковых символов. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Добавил весь код:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #define MAXSIZE 1024
    int INPUTNUMBER(int a);
    int STRINGINPUT(char *a, int b, int id);
    void EDITTEXT(char **a, int y, char *b, int dsize);

int main() {

int dsize, num = 0, hit, xhit, yhit, x, y, i;
char *del = NULL;
char *mas = NULL;
char **text = NULL;

//ввод строки разделителей
printf("Enter delimeters: ");
del = (char*)malloc(MAXSIZE, sizeof(char));
dsize = STRINGINPUT(del, MAXSIZE, 0);
del = (char *)realloc(del, dsize * sizeof(char));
del[dsize] = 0;
puts(del);

//ввод числа
while (num == 0 || num > dsize+1) {
    num = INPUTNUMBER(dsize);
}

//ввод текста
for (y = 0, yhit = 0; yhit == 0; y++) {
    printf("String %d: ", y);
    text = (char**)realloc(text, (y + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    mas = (char*)malloc(MAXSIZE, sizeof(char));
    x = STRINGINPUT(mas, MAXSIZE, 1);
    mas = (char*)realloc(mas, x * sizeof(char));
    text[y] = (char*)malloc(x * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        text[y][i] = mas[i];
    }
    text[y][x] = 0;
    puts(text[y]);
    for (i = 0, hit = 0; i < dsize; i++) {
        for (xhit = 0; xhit < x; xhit++) {
            if (text[y][xhit] == del[i]) {
                xhit = x;
                hit++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (hit == num + 1) yhit++;
}

EDITTEXT(text, y, del, dsize);

return 0;
}

int INPUTNUMBER(int a) {
char *s;
int num = 0;

while (num == 0) {
    printf("Enter number (0;%d]: ", a - 1);
    s = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    gets(s);
    num = atoi(s);
}

return (num);
}

void EDITTEXT(char **a, int y, char *b, int dsize) {
int i, x, d = 0, k;

for (i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
    for (x = 0; a[i][x] != 0; x++) {
        for (k = 0; k < dsize; k++) {
            if (a[i][x] == b[k]) d++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", d);
}

int STRINGINPUT(char *a, int b, int id) {
int i = 0, hit = 0, x, xhit;
for (i = 0; hit == 0; i++) {
    a[i] = getc(stdin);
    if (a[i] == '\n') hit++;
    if (id == 0) {
        for (x = 0, xhit = 0; xhit == 0 && x < i; x++) {
            if (a[i] == a[x]) {
                xhit++;
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
a[i] = 0;
return i;
}
```

Comment: Условие в цикле `i <= y;` это потенциальный выход за пределы массива.

Comment: Ну, возможную причину вам указали. А чтоб помочь с заданием - уточните его (количество одинаковых символов где? В массиве? В строке `b`? Каких именно одинаковых? Если есть строка `aabbaa` - то что говорить в ответ - 2 или 4, грубо говоря... Словом, без ясного ТЗ результат - ХЗ...

Comment: Покажите весь контекст вашей ошибки: без него не оч. понятно в чём ошибка

Comment: Покажите как делаете (объявляете) массив `a` в вызывающей программе

Answer (score 0):

Я толком не понял что вы хотели сказать, но скорее всего ваша должна программа выглядит вот так:

```c
typedef unsigned long uint32;
typedef char* string;

int findCharCount(const string* lines, const uint32 lineCount, const string chars) {
    // checks

    uint32 count = 0;

    for (uint32 i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i)
        for (char* chr = lines[i]; *chr; ++chr)
            for (char cmp = chars; *cmp; ++cmp)
                if (*chr == *cmp)
                    ++count;

    return count;
}
```

У вас нет никаких `x` и `y`. Это не двумерный массив, а вложенный.

Двумерный массив:

```
     sizeX
      /\
      ||
+-----++-----+
|            |
01 02 03 04 05-+
02 03 04 05 06 |
03 04 05 06 07 +-> sizeY
04 05 06 07 08 |
05 06 07 08 09-+
```

Вложенный массив:

```
[01 02 03 04 05]
[37 05 11]
[37 95 17 00 37 10 58 55 85 36 14 07]
```